# Power radiated by a vertically oriented bar magnet rotating around a vertical axis?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields

One very interesting problem:

How to calculate a bar magnet (in vertical direction) rotating around a vertical axis, to radiate the electromagnetic waves?

For instance, please see the figure below:

[image]

typical parameters:

distance between the bar and the axis: R

length of the bar magnet: L  (in the same order of magnitude of R, e.g. R=2L)

rotating angular velocity: $\omega$

max strength of magnetic field of the bar magnet at the poles：B

So, how to calculate the radiation power and the distribution please?

Or, could you please list any reference to solve such problem or similar ones？

Thank you very much and merry Xmas!

Comment: See CLASSICAL ELECTRODYNAMICS by John David Jackson, JOHN WILEY & SONS, INC. NEW YORK - LONDON 1962
9.3. Magnetic dipole and electric quadrupole fields

Comment: The only property of the magnet that should matter is its dipole moment, not quantities like L and B. @AlexTrounev: I don't think it's going to radiate any M1 or E2 radiation. The magnetic dipole moment and electric quadrupole moment are both constant. I think it would be M2 (magnetic quadrupole) radiation.

Comment: @BenCrowell The magnetic dipole is not constant as it rotates. It is necessary to calculate what will be the radiation from the magnetic dipole, which rotates while maintaining the orientation parallel to the axis of rotation at some distance from the axis.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: The dipole moment is invariant under translations, so yes, it is constant during this motion.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you for the comment! However, I guess the B field from the magnet varies periodically at some specific position around this source, so it would still produce the EMWs, though as   you mentioned, the moment indeed remains a stationary vector. Is it?

Comment: @BenCrowell Thank you for your comment and editing the title! :)

Comment: @BenCrowell Rotation is not a translation (in geometry). I think that it is necessary to calculate the radiation. Then everything will become clear.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: *Rotation is not a translation (in geometry).* You seem confused here. If you think the dipole moment is changing during this motion, then please show a calculation of how it changes. *I think that it is necessary to calculate the radiation. Then everything will become clear.* I've calculated the M1 radiation rate. Here's my calculation: it's zero, because the magnetic dipole moment is constant.